# SQL Trigger on DELETE does not return data when a combination factor exists

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sql-delete

I need to LOG payment deletion from out database. The issue I have is that when a payment is marked in our system for multiple invoices the trigger does not return the number of the invoice, but instead gives NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOG_DELETEDPAYMENTS
BEFORE DELETE ON payments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :old.type IN(2, 3) THEN 
INSERT INTO TABLE_LOG_DELETEDPAYMENTS (table_name, invnr, extinvnr, invdate, transactionid, info, createdby, deleted_by, date_of_change)
values ('payments', :old.invnr, :old.extinvnr, :old.invdate, :old:transactionid, :old.info, :old.createdby, sys_context('userenv','OS_USER'), SYSDATE);
END IF;
END;
```

The combining factor is `transactionid`. In our DB 1 `transactionid` can include multiple invoices and payments within it. When I delete 1 `transactionid` all payments with this value are deleted as well. In the image below you can see an example. The first row has `invid`, but rows 2 and 3 (they were paid combined with same `transactionid`) do not have any values:

[image: Example]

How can I change this and get in the table all `invoiceid`'s?

Comment: That's not trigger's problem, but the PAYMENT table's as it contains invoice numbers (that's :OLD.INVNR, isn't it?). So, if it is NULL in PAYMENT, then trigger fetches NULL and stores it into TABLE_LOG_DELETEDPAYMENTS.

Comment: You are correct here. The strange thing is when its single payment then the invnr gets recorded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74189891/how-to-include-a-subselect-in-values-of-insert-to-take-values-from-different-row). It is with example and the easiest solution to modify and work with.